# mock elastic search innerhits

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, moq, nest

I have read the document https://gist.github.com/netoisc/5d456850d79f246685fee23be2469155
which well know how to mock elasticsearch query
But I have a case which return result have innerhits

```
Documents = searchResult.Hits.Select(
                    h => {
                        
                            if (h.InnerHits.TryGetValue("books", out var data)) {
                                ht.Source.Books = data!.Documents<book>();
                            }

                            ht.Source.Books = ht.Source.Books.Where(k=>k.country=="US");
                        
                        return h.Source;
                    })
```

From my mock test
I have do this

```
var innerHitResult = new Mock<InnerHitsResult>();
innerHitResult.SetupGet(s => s.Documents<book>()).Returns(new List<book>());
var innerHitDictionary = new Dictionary<string, InnerHitsResult> {
            {
                "books", innerHitResult.Object
            }
        };
```

I've got the error on innerHitResult.SetupGet , which error say :

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a property access: s => s.Documents<book>()
```

Even I use innerHitResult.Setup is not working
Can I know how to do mock for inner hit ?

In the other simple example
if I have a class :

```
public class BlogSearchResult
    {
        public InnerMetaData Hits { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<T> Document<T>() where T : class => Hits.Documents<T>();
    }
```

I want to mock BlogSearchResult which want to do

```
var blogs = fixture.CreateMany<Blog>();
            var blogSearch = new Mock<BlogSearchResult>();
            blogSearch.SetupGet(s => s.Document<Blog>()).Returns(blogs);
or 
blogSearch.Setup(s => s.Document<Blog>()).Returns(blogs);
```

They are all return error, is that possible ?

Comment: `SetupGet` is for faking property gets. use `Setup` instead.

Comment: I use setup and it return not support function expression on s => s.Documents<book>()